# URLError from rejecting a URLAuthenticationChallenge is too generic

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, public-key-pinning

According to [this article](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703234) when communicating with hardware accessories in your local network over HTTPS securely, you should be pinning your certificates like this:

In the `URLSessionDelegate` implement this method:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) async -> (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?)
```

Then do your verification via `SecTrustEvaluateWithError` and return `(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: trust))` if it was successful and `(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)` if it was not.

However, the error returned when rejecting the challenge in `try await URLSession(...).data(from:)` is a `URLError` with the code -999 which is `URLError.Code.cancelled`.

How would I distinguish between other cancellations, so I could tell the user that the request failed because of an invalid certificate? [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/code/2883178-cancelled) of `URLError.Code.cancelled` is very generic, so I cannot solely rely on this error (or can I?).

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/handling_an_authentication_challenge/performing_manual_server_trust_authentication) suggests that we should be showing the error right in the `URLSessionDelegate` which does not seem like a good solution to me since user interface code would leak into networking code.

Are there any other techniques, I could apply here to specifically catch the error from `URLSession` when the certificate was declined by my own validation logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve this issue with a custom "HTTPClient" which internally uses a URLSession, and a URLSession API where you can specify a *task specific delegate*.

The idea is, to use a dedicated *task specific delegate*, where you store the error of that request. Then, later when the URLSession data tasks returns with a cancellation error, check the delegate's error property if there is more information.

The below code give you an idea to start with:

First, you need a class conforming to `URLSessionTaskDelegate`, which can be instantiated as a separate object. In your case it specifies delegate method which handles the authentication challenge.

Define the delegate:

```
final class AuthenticationChallengeHandler: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate  {
    
    struct Error: LocalizedError {
        var errorDescription: String? {
            "server authentication failed"
        }
    }
    
    init(expectedCertificate: SecCertificate? = nil) {
        self.expectedCertificate = expectedCertificate
    }
   
    private var expectedCertificate: SecCertificate?
    
    
    var error: Error?

    func shouldAllowHTTPSConnection(trust: SecTrust) async -> Bool {
        self.error = Error()
        return false
    }

    
    func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge
    ) async -> (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) {
        switch challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod {
        case NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust:
            let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
            guard await self.shouldAllowHTTPSConnection(trust: trust) else {
                return (.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            }
            let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
            return (.useCredential, credential)
        default:
            return (.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Note, that the delegate has a property `error`.

Second, you want to use a dedicated instance of this delegate for executing a single request. Here, you can use the following URLSession APIs which have a parameter for a *dedicated* URLSessionTaskDelegate. For example:

```
    /// Convenience method to load data using a URL, creates and 
    /// resumes a URLSessionDataTask internally.
    ///
    /// - Parameter url: The URL for which to load data.
    /// - Parameter delegate: Task-specific delegate.
    /// - Returns: Data and response.
    public func data(
        from url: URL, 
        delegate: (URLSessionTaskDelegate)? = nil
    ) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)
```

You can then use it like below:

```
    func testExample() async throws {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
        let delegate = AuthenticationChallengeHandler()
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(
               from: url, 
               delegate: delegate
            )
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print(delegate.error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
```

Of course, you should improve this above code in your custom "HTTPClient" implementation.